# Modifying a SELECT query

Tags: sql, select

I have a query like this:

```
 SELECT initials, name
 FROM employee e, projects p
 WHERE e.country = p.country
```

Until now, both tables used an abbreviation for the country columns. Like `"SWE"` for Sweden and `"ITA"` for Italy.

In the future, the employee table will use names for the country columns. Like "Sweden" and "Italy".

Is it somehow possible to change my query so it can match abbreviations with names? Like `"SWE" = "Sweden"` and `"ITA" = "Italy"`.

Thanks.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would be better to have an own country table and the other tables referencing to that.

```
country table
-------------
id
name
abbreviation
```

Comment: Correct, but What the heck do you need the "id" column for? The abbreviation is already a viable primary key.

Comment: I prefer referencing a number as foreign key in other tables instead of a string.

Comment: It just makes no sense in this case, since a CHAR(3) column will take less space than an integer.

Comment: Not necessarily. Using a `smallint` uses only 2 bytes.

Comment: Fine, it won't make a difference for this table either way. (But secretly I'm judging you :-) )

Comment: And I have to live with that :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the best solution is creating a third table where you match the current abbreviation with the full country name. You can then join both tables on that.

```
CountryTable (countryAbbreviation, countryName)
```

The select would then be something like this:

```
SELECT initials, name
FROM employee e JOIN countryTable c ON c.countryName = c.country 
    JOIN projects p ON p.country = c.countryAbbreviation
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I fafor the solution by juergen, another solution will be altering the two tables to the new format.

```
UPDATE employee
SET country = "SWEDEN"
WHERE country = "SWE"
```

Do this for all the countries you have.

Answer (score 0):

Always in country table, if country name starts with first three letters of the country in the employee table then you can use substring operator

```
SELECT initials, name
FROM employee e, projects p
WHERE upper(substring(e.country,1,3)) = upper(p.country)
```

Comment: That's just asking for future bugs, see "India" vs. "Indonesia"